# Trigger not compatible between SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2012

On a version of SQL Server 2008, we have the following trigger code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerName] 
ON [dbo].[SQLTable] 
FOR UPDATE, INSERT 
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM inserted 
       WHERE NOT (Column1 >= 0 AND Column1 <= 100)) > 0
   BEGIN
       RAISERROR 44444 ' >= 0 And <= 100'
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END
   ........
```

Which seems working fine on SQL Server 2008 but not anymore on SQL Server 2012. On SQL Server 2012, it's always raising an error.

When I'm updating the trigger with, it's working on SQL Server 2012

```
From TableName Join Inserted
```

If it's not supported, what is the alternative ?

Do we just have to install a SQL Server 2008 again or do we have to adapt all the SQL code ?

Is there a list with deprecated features between SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 ?

Thank you for your support

Comment: What error do you get???

Comment: What is this? `RAISERROR 44444 '>=0 And <=100'`

Comment: I don't have any error. It's always showing the Error message. It's always going into Begin RAISEERROR ...... ROLLBACK Transaction END Even if we try to insert a value of 90 or 200

Comment: Who is showing error message? `I don't have any error. It's always showing the Error message.`. Do you have some problems with predicate logic?

Comment: use `WHERE NOT (Column1>=0 And Column1<=100))` (i.e. drop the `> 0` at the end)

Comment: did you change anything exept the server version?

Comment: How do you compile this `RAISERROR 44444 '>=0 And <=100'`. Is not this throwing error?

Comment: `if we try to insert a value of 90 or 200` - shouldn't it throw error on 200? Can you explain what you want to check?

Comment: the error is shown on the application and when executing an insert manually into the database (running a simple insert into query). But my issue is by executing the same insert into query or executing the same application connected to SQL Server 2008 it's working and not when it's connected to SQL Server 2012 :(

Comment: is it really the expected error?

Comment: We have only changed the SQL Server version. By adapting the SQL Code using FROM Table Join Inserted instead of From Inserted, it's working on SQL Server 2012.